# Cleaner way to split a querystring without HttpUtility

Tags: c#, parsing, lambda, xamarin, split

I have a Xamarin application that parses a scanned QR code that contains a query string.  Occasionally users scan other codes that cannot get split into a dictionary.  I wrote the following based on some examples I found, but it seems a little ugly:

```
var parts = query.Split(new[] { '&' });

try
{
    return parts.Select (
            part => part.Split (new [] { '=' }))
                        .ToDictionary(
                           pair => { try { return pair [0]; } catch { return string.Empty; } }, 
                           pair => { try { return pair [1]; } catch { return string.Empty; } }
                        );
}
catch 
{ 
    return null; // eat
}
```

Is there a better way to solve this issue?

Comment: Why don't you want to use HttpUtility? Edit: nevermind, I see now. "Occasionally users will scan random barcodes that cannot get split into a dictionary."

Comment: Any possibility of using a regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform a pre-validation of the url you're receiving from QR code scanner. This will allow you to get rid of hacks done for swallowing exceptions using empty catch.

```
    public IDictionary<string, string> GetParams(string query)
    {
        // Perform a validation if URL is valid
        var regex = @"^http(s)?://([\w-]+.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=])?$";
        Regex validator = new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.Compiled);
        if (!validator.IsMatch(query))
        {
            return null;
            // or
            // throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Url");
        }

        var parts = query.Split('?')[1].Split('&');

        return parts.Select(part => part.Split(new[] { "=" }, 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                .ToDictionary(
                pair =>
                {
                    return pair[0];
                },
                pair =>
                {
                    return pair[1];
                }
            );
    }
```

Parsing the query strings to dictionary is more convenient to access than using regex for parsing.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a regular expression is what you're looking for. It solves the validation problem and avoids the first Split and the Select

```
string validUrl = "http://www.contoso.com/data?foo=bar&bar=foo";                

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(validUrl, @"(\?|\&)([^=]+)\=([^&]+)"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value.TrimStart('&','?'));
}
```